# How to customize Zurb Foundation 6 close button

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

The [Close Button](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/close-button.html) seems to be a good way for displaying a notice which the user can click away. But its usage remains rather elusive to a newb.

I have placed one on a page:

```
   <div>
     <div class="callout" data-closable="slide-out-left">
       <button class="close-button" data-close>&times;</button>
       <p>whatever notice text</p>
   </div>
```

But now I am unaware of any way of changing its color the Zurb way, or where to find closing animation options other than this one I use above. I would like the button to be colored e.g. as a Zurb success, and a fade out effect rather than the confusingly fast slide out effect. How do I go about that?

Actually I would also like the button to tightly wrap around the notice text, not take up the whole line width. Is that doable in any Zurb-idiomatic way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of close button or other style, you can code the CSS like

```
.close-button{
   color:red;
}
```

If you are using SASS you can customize the variables.
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/close-button.html#sass-reference

The animations you can use are:

```
slide-in-down
slide-in-left
slide-in-up
slide-in-right
slide-out-down
slide-out-left
slide-out-up
slide-out-right
fade-in
fade-out
hinge-in-from-top
hinge-in-from-right
hinge-in-from-bottom
hinge-in-from-left
hinge-in-from-middle-x
hinge-in-from-middle-y
hinge-out-from-top
hinge-out-from-right
hinge-out-from-bottom
hinge-out-from-left
hinge-out-from-middle-x
hinge-out-from-middle-y
scale-in-up
scale-in-down
scale-out-up
scale-out-down
spin-in
spin-out
spin-in-ccw
spin-out-ccw
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/motion-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add the callout to a column 1 to 12 wide (although 12 wide is what you already have with the callout on its own). Here I have added it to a 2 wide column. By removing the slide-out method it uses the default fade-out.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
        <div class="success callout" data-closable>
            <button class="close-button" data-close>&times;</button>
            <p>whatever notice text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]